# How to mock PHP inbuilt methods in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-6

I have a Model method like

```
public static function getBusinessCardFieldsOptions() {
    return implode(',', array_values(self::SEND_BUSINESS_CARD_FIELD));
}
```

And I wanted to make an assertion that the implode and array_values method has been called at least once. Does anyone know how to mock PHP inbuilt methods?

Comment: why would you think to assert such things?

Comment: You can't do that unless you (somehow) modify the php binary code during program execution (which is not unheard of, but not simple), and in your particular case you shouldn't be doing that anyway. If you assert that `array_values` was called that means that whenever you change the **implementation** of your class your tests will break . What you want is for your tests to break when the **result** changes regardless of how the function is implemented

Comment: making more assertions makes our test more reliable and also tests aren't only for testing the results but also every line of code you have written.